# How does one access custom fileds in an ACF relation field in GraphQL?

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby.js with the WP API. Typically you can use GraphiQL to mess with queries and the autocomplete will help answer questions like this. But I think either the utility didn't factor this level of inception or I'm not using graphQL correctly...

```
  query workInnerPageQuery{
    wordpressPage(id: { eq: "e52ad032-9468-5826-9320-a22da5b1e0c9" }) {
      id
      title
      acf{
        case_studies{ // this is a relation field
          post_title
          post_name
          --- how do you get an ACF field here?
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have a custom field "subtitle" for example. This doesn't work...

```
  acf{
    case_studies{
      post_title
      post_name
      acf{
        subtitle
      }
    }
  }
```

Seeing as subtitle is an acf field of the post type "case_study" which is a relation item on this specific page... how does one access an ACF field within an ACF field?

Has anyone else had to figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my google skills suck. This is possible with a plugin:
https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api-recursive

Install that plugin on your wordpress site, then add this to your functions file:

```
add_filter('acf/rest_api/recursive/types', function( $types ) {
  $types += array(
    'case_studies' => 'case_studies'
  );
    return $types;
} );
```

keep in mind, case_studies is my post type. You obviously need to add yours to the array.

Then you can access acf recursively in graphql as expected...

```
  acf{
    case_studies{
      post_title
      post_name
      acf{
        subtitle
      }
    }
  }
```

I would delete this post, but I think it is useful to have this listed on stack overflow.